# Como puedo imprimir los valores de un TreeMap?

Tags: java, map

No me devuelve nada esto: `System.out.println(tree.values());`, tampoco funcionan los castings, i.e.   `System.out.println((int)tree.values());`

Como le hago para que imprima la coleccion de valores key?

```
Map<Integer,String> tree=new TreeMap<>();
tree.values();//Devuelve una colección de los valores contenidos en 
//este mapa.
System.out.println(tree.values());
```

Comment: Puedes agregar la implementacion de `tree`.

Comment: aah como? @David

Comment: Se refiere a como estás creando el objeto tree.

Comment: pues asi: `Map<Integer,String> tree=new TreeMap<>();` @Ali pero ese no es el problema

Comment: Para valores se usa `values()` para claves `keySet()`  [Ejemplo](https://repl.it/Lc12/3) no es necesario un `foreach` para imprimirlos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `values` de la clase `TreeMap` devuelve un objecto de tipo `Collection` por lo que no se puede imprimir así nada más a menos que le hagas un `toString` al `collection`: `System.out.println(tree.values().toString())`

Para imprimir un `Collection`, basta con recorrerlo, puedes usar el `foreach`, en tu caso como los valores son de tipo `String`, quedaría así:

```
for (String obj : tree.values()) {
   System.out.println(obj); // 
}
```

Si lo que deseas es imprimir los `keys`, puedes usar el método`tree.keySet()` que te devuelve un `Set` que al final también hereda de Collection por lo que lo puedes recorrer de la misma forma:

```
for (Integer obj : tree.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(obj); // 
}
```

Comment: aah pense que cuando decía valores se refería a los keys de los datos, osea los numeros enteros

Comment: No, si deseas imprimir los keys, usa el método `tree.keySet()` y lo recorres de la misma manera.

Answer (score 2):

Como añadido a la respuesta de Ali, usando Java 8:

```
// valores
tree.values().forEach(System.out::println);

// claves
tree.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);

// entradas
tree.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.println("Clave: " + entry.getKey() + " -> Valor: " + entry.getValue()));
```